# How to Implement python module into drop-down?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a script pre-written that takes a source folder (folderA) and moves all modified or new files from the past 24 hrs into a destination folder (folderB). Now I am creating a GUI that gives the option to chose the src and dst folders through a drop down. So far I have created this basic GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()


# Source Folder 
label = ttk.Label(root, text = "Choose your source folder!")
label.pack()

srcoptions = StringVar()
combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable = srcoptions)
combobox.pack()
combobox.config(values = ('folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'folder4'))



# Destination Folder 
label = ttk.Label(root, text = "Choose your source folder!")
label.pack()

dstoptions = StringVar()
combobox = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable = dstoptions)
combobox.pack()
combobox.config(values = ('folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3', 'folder4'))



# Trigger move files button
button = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Move Files')
button.pack()
def callback():
    print('Files Moved!')
```

I don't know exactly how to link the users correct folders into the drop down menus. I am fairly new to programming, even more so Python, so any suggestions/leads on how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have am aware of `root.fileName = filefiledialog.askdirectory`but am not aware on how to implement this into a drop down. I have looked through stack overflow and not able to find solution relative to my problem.

Comment: `Button(..., command=callback)`

Comment: `fileName = filefiledialog.askdirectory()` can be without `root.` but it need `()` at the end.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not seeing how this would create a list of the users folders in a drop-down. @furas

Comment: It is only comment to code, not solution. Belowe is place for answer and solution.